# how to format text to align in two columns

Tags: css

First off the title may not be clear but i dont know to come up with a better one.

i have text that I put in a td cell in a velocity template, something like below

```
* My name
is what?
```

what i want is something that more formatted like below.

```
* My name
  is what?
```

"My name is what?" is variable i print and all i do is concatinate * to it and put in the cell for display

what can be done to make it happen. i am not sure of the best way to start off with. I use IE8

Comment: Still unclear what you want. Post the current code you've tried so far.

Comment: Just to clarify your issue, you want the * to show to the left of the copy block, and want the text to wrap aligned to the first word of the copy block?

Comment: @badAdviceGuy yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: There are couple of ways to achieve this. It depends on the markup.

Comment: would be great if you could share those couple of ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution that may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/5jk3M/)**

Instead of separating content into different elements and positioning them (or nesting them). I thought a simple before class could work well in this situation.

HTML:

```
<div class="copy-block">
  My name is what?
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.copy-block {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.copy-block:before {
    content: "*";
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: 3px;    
}
```

Comment: .copy-block:before is not showing up in IE8 otherwise it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The name is variable. The output on two lines can be solved with adding a break in the table cell.

```
table {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: 12px arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.asterix-name {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
}
.asterix-name:before {
   content:'* ';
   position: absolute;
   left: 5px;
   top: 0.5em;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="asterix-name">My name<br> is what?</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fb7jT/49/

Comment: .asterix-name:before is not showing up in IE8 otherwise it works fine

Comment: Checked with modern.ie virtual box set up XP IE8. It works fine there. Did you check http://jsfiddle.net/Fb7jT/49/show/?